# Creating a UrlEncodedFormEntity from a List of NameValuePairs throws a NullPointerException

Tags: java, post, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm creating a unit test to try out the servlet I just created.

```
@Test
public void test() throws ParseException, IOException {

  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/WebService/MakeBaby");

  List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("father_name", "Foo"));
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mother_name", "Bar"));

  post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
  HttpResponse response = null;

  try {
    response = client.execute(post);
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  String stringifiedResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

  System.out.println(stringifiedResponse);

  assertNotNull(stringifiedResponse);
}
```

The following line generates a NullPointerException:

```
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just solved it by adding the utf-8 format.

```
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "utf-8"));
```

Creating a [`UrlEncodedFormEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity.html) without passing the format will use `DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET` which is `ISO-8859-1`

Which baffles me... what's causing it to throw `NullPointerException`?

Comment: I think you can accept your answer now. I had the same exception and adding the encoding solved my issue. Thank you.

Comment: I think this is not stupid question with 10 like :), my problem is also similar to you Thanks.

Comment: This saved the day for me: I had utf-8 values in the the pairs, and thus they weren't being encoded correctly - it was tossing the utf-8 character, as ISO-8859-1 would do! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Not a stupid question at all.  I think the confusion is that in httpclient 4.1, no encoding format was required- This worked:

```
HttpEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params);
method.setEntity(entity);
```

When I changed the dependency to httpclient 4.2 in order to access [URIBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html), I got:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity.<init>(StringEntity.java:70)
at org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity.<init>(UrlEncodedFormEntity.java:78)
at org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity.<init>(UrlEncodedFormEntity.java:92)...
```

With 4.2, it seems the constructor requires the encoding, as you noted.  Confusingly, the doc specifies that the old constructor is still available, but it doesn't seem to work anymore.

public UrlEncodedFormEntity(List parameters) [doc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity.html#UrlEncodedFormEntity(java.util.List))

Comment: Seems like this is a known regression: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hc-httpclient-users/201205.mbox/%3C1337953593.2732.38.camel@ubuntu%3E