# HttpPost in android not working

Tags: android, http-post

I am trying to connect to apache tomcat server using HTTP POST, when i see LOG file of server it showing **GET /login/validate_doc.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 685** ,

which means it is getting a GET request when i am sending using HttpPost and form parameters are not received by server.

my code is below:

```
        HttpPost post_http=null;
        post_http=new HttpPost("http://somexx.ac.in/medONmob/validate_doc.jsp");
        try 
        {

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));

            post_http.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Where am i wrong ...??? Help me out please

Comment: @abhinav-Try this - post_http.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8) );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying encoding when constructing UrlEncodedFormEntity. By default it is ISO-8859-1.
Also this will make your code future safe

[Creating a UrlEncodedFormEntity from a List of NameValuePairs throws a NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942205/creating-a-urlencodedformentity-from-a-list-of-namevaluepairs-throws-a-nullpoint)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are using a post, then you probably are sending data on your request body, Am I right?, then you have to specify the content-type of the data you are sending in the headers, in order to execute a proper post:). For example if I am sending a json in the request body then I should add a header like this:

request.addHeader("content-type", "text/json");

Cheers