# Passing values to server by HttpPost Android

Tags: android, http-post

I am trying to post some values to server by Http post method but I am always getting this error:

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Not Found 
Detail message - not found
```

I am using KeyValue pair method to send values, Please hep me in this, Any help would be appreciated.

Code - 
`HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();`

```
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 1000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 1000);
HttpParams p = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(p);
String url = "myurl";
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
try {
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                        7);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",
                        "test"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",
                        "ramos"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fullname",
                        "mark"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",
                        "yyy@gmail.com"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile_prefix",
                        "91"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile_suffix",
                        "1234567890"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mode", "app"));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                        responseHandler);
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: added by code.Please check

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371016/httppost-in-android-not-working/